# Angular Contact form email submission issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have created a contact [Click here for example](http://jsfiddle.net/nfjhj22s/1/) i believe i have created all the credentials needed for this form, however when i sent the message to the email credentials highlighted in my code, i don't an email submission from the sender. Does anyone know how this problem can be solved ?

```
angular
.module('hfApp')
.controller('contactCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.success = false;
    $scope.error = false;
    $scope.send = function () {
        var htmlBody ='<div>Name: ' + $scope.user.name + '</div>' +
                      '<div>Email: ' + $scope.user.email + '</div>' +
                      '<div>Message: ' + $scope.user.body + '</div>' +
                      '<div>Date: ' + (new Date()).toString() + '</div>';

        $http({
            url: 'http://www.hfpersonaltrainer.com/',
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                'From': 'foo@foo.com',
                'To': 'nate.tyrone@gmail.com',
                'HtmlBody': htmlBody,
                'Subject': 'New Contact Form Submission'
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Postmark-Server-Token': '8569dcd45-6a1a-4e7b-ae75-ea37629de4'
            }
        }).
        success(function (data) {
            $scope.success = true;
            $scope.user = {};
        }).
        error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = true;
        });
    };
}])
```

Comment: have u seen this / http://www.chaosm.net/blog/2014/05/21/angularjs-contact-form-with-bootstrap-and-phpmailer/

Comment: meh... thanks for the link above but it's defeating the purpose of what i trying to do.

Comment: What purpose is it defeating? What error are you getting? You realize the above code is going to just try and do the http request as soon as the controller is instantiated, right? You need to put the request inside of a function that is called when you click the Submit button.

Comment: @Scott i am not receiving any errors messages, it's actually saying the email has been sent once i have submitted, however i am not recieveing the email in my inbox

Comment: You are liking getting an error on the www.hfpersonaltrainer.com side. It has to be listening for json posts in order to know how to send an email. Try looking there.